# change the content of a page without changing url in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I changed my route without changing the url by using the skipLocationChange attribute like below.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/articledetail']" skipLocationChange><h4>{{article.HeadLine}}</h4></a>
```

But it goes to previous route while I am refreshing the page.

Then I used ngIf to check a variable value by setting value of it in a method which is called  while clicking on anchor tag,.But here also,my contents are previous contents after refreshing the page

How can I change the content of a page without changing the url while clicking an anchor tag in angular 2.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to child routes? If yes, you will need a router-outlet in the main parent, so that all childs can be loaded into that.

Comment: Thanks.I used <router-outlet> ,But for that url will be changed right?.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad. So in your situation, it goes to the previous route instead of staying in the current one? So it goes one step back in the browser history?

Comment: yes.so, I used "this.location.replaceState('/articledetail');" to change the state.my route is changed before navigation itself.After clicking on anchor tag it should goes to next route and should not change url .So,we can't achieve this using skiplocationchange.Pls give me any other idea to achieve this.

Comment: I am not to familiar with `replaceState`. Maybe try the `replaceUrl` property e.g: `this.router.navigate(["articledetail"], {replaceUrl:false});`

Comment: thanks.this is working like skiplocationchange only

Comment: I used ngIf to check a variable value by setting value of it in a method which is called  while clicking on anchor tag,.But here also,my contents are previous contents after refreshing the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  used ngIf to check a variable value by setting value of it in a method which is called while clicking on anchor tag,.But here also,my contents are previous contents after refreshing the page

In app.component.html

```
            <div class="row b-r" *ngIf="region==='INDIA'">
             INDIA Region
            .........
            .........
            </div>
           <div class="row b-r" *ngIf="region==='US'">

            US Region
            ................
             ..............
             .....
           </div>
       <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" [routerLink]="'/'" 
       (click)="ChangeRegion('US')">US</a>
       <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" [routerLink]="'/'" 
        (click)="ChangeRegion('INDIA')">INDIA</a>
```

In app.compoenent.ts

```
     ngOnInit() {

          //Using localstorage for retaining region value after refreshing the page
       if (localStorage.getItem("region") === null) {
          this.region = "INDIA";
         }
      else {
       this.region = localStorage.getItem("region");
        }
      }
         region: string;

    ChangeRegion(region) {
       this.region = region;

     localStorage.setItem("region", this.region);

        }
```

So,that I used localstorage to retain my variable value after refreshing the page.Its working fine

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz and show us the issue? It does not seem to be normal.

Comment: issue has been fixed.pls see my answer.Thanks